# Datetime compare doesn't match

Tags: powershell, datetime

I want to compare a date which I get from a xml file with a "lastwritetime" of a file. Powershell ISE shows the same for both but my if does not return true. I tried some datetime casts but this doesn't help as well.

My XML:

```
<meta>
    <log path="D:\tomcat.log">
        <lastwrite>08/03/2015 13:44:09</lastwrite>
    </log>
</meta>
```

My powershell script:

```
[xml]$log_meta = Get-Content "D:\log_meta.xml"
$node = $log_meta.meta.log | where {$_.path -eq "D:\tomcat.log"}

(ls "D:\tomcat.log").LastWriteTime
$node.lastwrite

if((ls "D:\tomcat.log").LastWriteTime -eq $node.lastwrite){
    "Date and time is the same"
}
```

Third line displays: (german date format)

```
Montag, 3. August 2015 13:44:09
```

Fourth line displays:

```
08/03/2015 13:44:09
```

But my if does not return true.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, it's working now. I converted both to strings.

```
(ls "D:\tomcat.log").LastWriteTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

I hoped I can work with datetimes, but maybe that's not possible. Thank you!

Comment: it seems to me that @yu_sha has gave you the answer, you should have accepted it as the valid one instead of "copying it" as your own one

Answer (score 2):

$node.lastwrite is a string (you read it from file) while LastWriteTime is DateTime. You need to convert them both to date, or both to DateTime.

If you convert both to DateTime, you'll need to round file time to the nearest second. On NTFS, file time has 100-nanosecond precision.

It's probably better to convert file time to string in the same format.

```
$writeTimeString = (ls "D:\tomcat.log").LastWriteTime.ToString("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: That's what I assumed. But I didn't find any way to do this. :(

Comment: Actually, I think that's not all. $node.lastwrite is a string (you read it from file) while LastWriteTime is a date.